# JavaScript command line calculator

Tags: javascript

I want to made calculator without buttons. 
Can you help me with function calculate?
I have two arrays, first array with numbers, and second with arithmetic operators.
In function calculate I must send one element from first array and one from second, but it dont work. In final program must give answer as number.
Can you explain me method reduce, can i send second array as a parameter?
Because in docs i find that it only sum elements.
Ill be very grateful if somebody write example of method reduce with function.
Here is my code.

```
var str = ("1+1+1+1-1*3");
var reg = /(\d+\.\d+)|\d+/g;

var myArray = str.match(reg);
var reg1 = /['+','-','*',"/"]/g;
var myArray2 = str.match(reg1);

console.log(myArray);
console.log(myArray2);



var i = 0;


function calculate(prev,curr,i){
if(myArray2[i] === "+"){
    // 
    curr = parseInt(prev,10)+parseInt(curr,10);
}

    else if(myArray2[i]==='-'){
        //
    curr = prev-curr;}

    else if(myArray2[i] ==='*'){
        //
        return prev*curr;
    }

    else{
        //
        return prev/curr;
    }
    }
var finAns = myArray.reduce(calculate);
alert ("Answer = " +finAns);
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: in this code returns NaN and my answer is how modify function calculate, that it return result depending on element of second array that consist of arithmetic operators

Comment: So you just want us to fix your code? That is not what Stack Overflow is for. Please read the [ask] page and [FAQ].

Comment: no, i want to somebody give me answer about reduce method, it is possible to send him second array as a paramether. Because i read that this method can only sum elements.

Comment: @user2424996 Here's documentation for Array.reduce() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce the parameters are documented.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `reduce` (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)) with your own function, but here you have some errors :

1. you should start calculation at index 1 since for the first element (`index = 0`), you have `curr = prev = the first element` (here 1)
2. your regex does not match the symbol `-` (you should escape it)

I have made a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6UyUq/.

---

EDIT : it does not take into account operators precedence as showed in @Jim Wharton's comment.....

Comment: The jsfiddle will produce an inaccurate result as it ignores the order of operations. Try it with `var str = ("4+8/2-3*2");` It will yield 6 instead of 2.